# ListBox ScrollIntoView and SelectedItem unreliable

Tags: c#, wpf

I currently have a list box set up as follows:

.xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="DetailsList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" LayoutUpdated="DetailsList_LayoutUpdated" />
```

.xaml.cs:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> details = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

In the window constructor:

```
DetailsList.DataContext = details;
```

I had a button that did the following:

```
details.Add(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss ") + someString);
DetailsList.UpdateLayout();
var lastItem = DetailsList.Items[DetailsList.Items.Count - 1];
DetailsList.SelectedItem = lastItem;
DetailsList.ScrollIntoView(lastItem);
```

That *should* select the last item in the list and scroll to it, but it only does it around 75% of the time. Instead, it will often select the second last and scroll to that instead.

I tried moving the scroll and selection into a LayoutUpdated event handler, no change.

I tried two separate buttons - one to add, one to select and scroll. If I add one item at a time then scroll, it seems to be slightly more reliable - it works 90% of the time. If I add half a dozen items before scrolling, it almost never works. It will typically select one of the new items, but not the last one.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug with System.Windows.Controls.ListBox?

Comment: What's 'someString'? Is it always the same value? I think there could be an equality issue going on here if you're pressing the button more than once per second.

Comment: I didn't think the value was important. Yes, for the button test it was a constant. Does that mean that there is no way to differentiate between elements with the same content? There are some cases where "real" data might be the same, and added multiple times in one second.

Comment: The value may matter. When you're setting a SelectedItem in a ListBox it will call the Equals method on its items in order to find the item to select. If you have two strings with the same text it won't be able to figure out which one you mean and you get the observed behaviour.

Comment: You will need some way to uniquely identify your list items. If your "real" data might be the same you won't be able to add strings directly to the list. You'd have to encapsulate them in a class. The default Equals method of that class should then take care of the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will cheat by adding milliseconds to the timestamps. It would be nice if there was simply a "scrollToEnd" method. It seems like a fairly common feature.

Comment: I've posted an answer so this question can be resolved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that multiple items with the same string value have been added to the list. When setting the `SelectedItem` property on the `ListView` it will call the `Equals` method to find the correct item. It will select the first item for which `Equals` returns true which is why you're getting the observed behaviour.

You need to add unique strings (e.g. add milliseconds) or wrap them in another class to be able to uniquely identify them.

Comment: I am adding items directly from a textbox is there a solution to get around this issue? rather than preventing the end user from adding the same item twice??